# Need help in using altField and/or altFormat for DatePicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-format

I have a relatively simple question regarding the Datepicker ....

I have a Datepicker now up and running, and I want the text field attached to the Datepicker to show the value in one format ("03/12/2012"), but when I want to get the date programatically, I want to get it in another pattern (e.g "2012-03-12") .. and I want to do this without having another text field where the date is put in the alternate format ... Can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, datepicker has this method: "getDate" that will return date.

Check out the documentation

Comment: getDate returns a full string like this: "Sat Mar 09 2012 00:00:00 GMT +0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)" .. This is not what I'm looking for ..

Comment: u should know that Javascript has object with type Date, and u can make use of it to get any string that you want. And take note that the return type of this function is Date